# How can I provide values for non-grouped columns in NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, group-by

I have a criteria query:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Sell043Report>()
  .SetProjection(.ProjectionList()
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.location))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.agent))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.cusip))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.SettlementDate))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.salePrice))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.foreignFx))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.batchNumber))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.origSaleDate))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.planName))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.GroupProperty<Sell043Report>(r => r.dateTimeAdded))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.Sum<Sell043Report>(r => r.shares))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.Sum<Sell043Report>(r => r.netMoney))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.Sum<Sell043Report>(r => r.grossMoney))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.Sum<Sell043Report>(r => r.taxWithheld))
    .Add(LambdaProjection.Sum<Sell043Report>(r => r.fees)))
  .List<Sell043Report>();
```

that generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  this_.location as y0_, 
  this_.agent as y1_, 
  this_.cusip as y2_, 
  this_.SettlementDate as y3_, 
  this_.salePrice as y4_, 
  this_.foreignFx as y5_, 
  this_.batchNumber as y6_, 
  this_.origSaleDate as y7_, 
  this_.planName as y8_, 
  this_.dateTimeAdded as y9_, 
  sum(this_.shares) as y10_, 
  sum(this_.netMoney) as y11_, 
  sum(this_.grossMoney) as y12_, 
  sum(this_.taxWithheld) as y13_,
  sum(this_.fees) as y14_ 
FROM 
  MIS_IPS_Sell043Report this_ 
GROUP BY
  this_.location,
  this_.agent,
  this_.cusip,
  this_.SettlementDate,
  this_.salePrice,
  this_.foreignFx,
  this_.batchNumber,
  this_.origSaleDate,
  this_.planName,
  this_.dateTimeAdded
```

however the Sell043Report table has additional columns than those listed in the SELECT statement so I'm receiving this error when attempting to get a list of Sell043Reports:

```
System.ArgumentException: The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "xyz.Sell043Report" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
```

I suspect the problem is that I'm not selecting all of the columns for a Sell043Report and so it doesn't know how to map the dataset to the object. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
SELECT 
  this_.location as y0_, 
  this_.agent as y1_, 
  this_.cusip as y2_, 
  this_.SettlementDate as y3_, 
  this_.salePrice as y4_, 
  this_.foreignFx as y5_, 
  this_.batchNumber as y6_, 
  this_.origSaleDate as y7_, 
  this_.planName as y8_, 
  this_.dateTimeAdded as y9_, 
  sum(this_.shares) as y10_, 
  sum(this_.netMoney) as y11_, 
  sum(this_.grossMoney) as y12_, 
  sum(this_.taxWithheld) as y13_,
  sum(this_.fees) as y14_,
  '' as Address1,
  '' as Address2 // etc
FROM 
  MIS_IPS_Sell043Report this_ 
GROUP BY
  this_.location,
  this_.agent,
  this_.cusip,
  this_.SettlementDate,
  this_.salePrice,
  this_.foreignFx,
  this_.batchNumber,
  this_.origSaleDate,
  this_.planName,
  this_.dateTimeAdded
```

How can I do this using NHibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely want something like this before the call to .List<>():

SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Result)))

Where Result is a new class you use to store the subset of columns you want as a result.

See also this question:

[Projections in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207329/projections-in-nhibernate)

The error you are getting is because without the call to SetResultTransformer, it wants to return an object array.  You are then (unintentionally) trying to cast that object array to a list of Sell043Report objects, which isn't possible.

Your other option is to remove the call to List<>() and instead deal with the object array.

Comment: @Michael I'd give you more points if I was able. =) Thanks! I've never heard of these transformers. It seems I missed a whole section of NHibernate.