# Can someone better explain what 'Projections' are in nHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-projections

As a new user of nHibernate and its utility library, fluent nhibernate, I am trying to learn enough to be dangerous with a good database.

I am having an exceptionally great deal of difficulty understanding the concept of **Projections**. Specifically, *What in the world are they?*

I have literally done exact searches on '*What are projections?*' and '*Projects in nHibernate*' and '*nHibernate, Projections, Definition*', etc. And I am still very confused. The most helpful posts so far are [This other StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207329/projections-in-nhibernate) and [This Blog Post by Colin Ramsay](https://colinramsay.co.uk/nhibernate/2008/01/15/nhibernate-optimising-queries-with-projections.html). But I am still vastly confused. My knowledge of databases is still entry-level at best.

I do not really understand what projections are, why I would want to use them, what they are accomplishing, etc. I see in the blog post that he is using them to get a list of integers (I presume Primary Keys) so that he can use them in a different query, but this is kind of nebulous in the way it is functioning and the why.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Here's a practical example.

Let's say that you have an online store and one of your domain classes is a `Brand` like "Samsung". This class has a boatload of properties associated with it, perhaps an integer `Identity`, a `Name`, a free-text `Description` field, a reference to a `Vendor` object, and so on.

Now let's say that you want to display a menu with a list of all the brands offered on your online store. If you just do `session.CreateCriteria<Brand>().List()`, then you are indeed going to get all of the brands. But you'll also have sucked all of the long `Description` fields and references to `Vendor`s from the database, and you don't need that to display a menu; you just need the `Name` and the `Identity`. Performance-wise, sucking all of this extra data down from the database slows things down and is unnecessary.

Instead, you can create a "projection" object that contains just the `Identity` and the `Name` calling it, say, `NameIdentityPair`:

```
public class NameIdentityPair
{
    public int Identity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you could tell NHibernate to only select the data that you really need to perform the task at hand by telling it to transform the result set onto your projection:

```
var brandProjections = this.session.CreateCriteria<Brand>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Name"), "Name")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Identity"), "Identity"))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<NameIdentityPair>())
    .List<NameIdentityPair>();

foreach (var brandProjection in brandProjections)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Identity: {0}, Name: {1}", 
        brandProjection.Identity, 
        brandProjection.Name);
}
```

Now you don't have a list of `Brand`s but instead a list of `NameIdentityPair`s, and NHibernate will have only issued a SQL statement like `SELECT b.Identity, b.Name from dbo.Brand b` to obtain this projection, as opposed to a massive SQL statement that grabs everything necessary to hydrate a `Brand` object (e.g., `SELECT b.Identity, b.Name, b.Description from dbo.brand b left join dbo.vendor v ....`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So projections are like query-side limiters, intead of query-result limiters. In a normal scenario, I would create the `NameIdentityPair` object and map my result to it from the query, but using Projection, I instead specify the exact filtering I demand right in the query, and that is all the database is aware of?

Comment: Many applications read more often than they write, so a common pattern is to use projections when reading from the database, and to use fully hydrated domain objects for saving to the database. This way, reading from the database is tuned for performance, and writing to the database is tuned to taking advantage of business logic (written in your domain classes) and the tool that you're using (NHibernate saving you from most of the CRUD code). The "projection" is kind of like plucking out what data you will need so that NHibernate only asks the database for just that data when it makes the SQL.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is much clearer than what I have found so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with SQL, a projection is the `SELECT` clause of a query, used to select which fields from the available results to return.

For example, assume you have a `Person` with `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address`, and `Phone` fields. If you want a query to return everything, you can leave off the projection, which is like `SELECT * FROM Person` in SQL. If you just want the first and last names, you would create a projection with `FirstName` and `LastName` -- which would be `SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person` in SQL terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use projections to call sql functions like SUM, COUNT... or select single fields without return an entity.

"...Retrieving only properties of an entity or entities, without the overhead of loading
the entity itself in a transactional scope. This is sometimes called a report
query; it’s more correctly called projection." [NHibernate in Action]