# Limit child entities without limiting parent entities - NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, left-join, fluent

I'm trying to limit the result set of a mapped collection.

Here is a simple model:

```
public class Table1 {
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Table2> Table2s { get; set; }
}


public class Table2 {
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual long Table1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Field { get; set; }
}

public class Table1Map : ClassMap<Table1> {
    public Table1Map () {
        Table("Table1");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").Not.Nullable().CustomType("Int64").GeneratedBy.Native();
        HasMany<Table2>(x => x.Table2s).Inverse().Not.LazyLoad().KeyColumns.Add("Table1Id").Fetch.Join();
    }
}

public class Table2Map : ClassMap<Table2> {
    public Table2Map () {
        Table("Table2");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").Not.Nullable().CustomType("Int64").GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Table1Id).Column("Table1Id").Not.Nullable().CustomType("Int64");
        Map(x => x.Field).Column("Field").Not.Nullable().CustomType("AnsiString").Length(25);
        References<Table1>(x => x.Table1, "Table1Id").Cascade.None();
    }
}
```

I want to select all `Table1`s.  I also want to select all `Table2`s that meet a certain criteria (`Table2.Field = 'value'`), but I don't want to limit my `Table1`s, so select null `Table2`s if they don't meet the criteria.  If I want to do this in SQL I'd do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id
WHERE
Table2.Field = 'value' or Table2.Field IS NULL
```

How should I structure my NHibernate query to achieve the desired result?  I'd like a list of `Table1`s, and within each `Table1` I'd like either an empty list of `Table2`s (because no `Table2`s met the criteria), or a list of `Table2`s that met the creteria.

I'm trying something like the following, but this will obviously not work:

```
List<Table1> result = new List<Table1>();
IQueryable<Table1> query = session.Query<Table1>();
if (value != null) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.Table2s.Field == value);
}
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible the way you do this. Hibernate loads the complete entity with all its properties (if not lazyloading is activated).
What should hibernate do, if you save such a loaded entity of type table1 without all table2's?

You should create some kind of viewobject (dvo) that contains the relevant parts of table1 and a list of table2 childs that fit the criteria. The select could possible be done by [projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207329/projections-in-nhibernate).

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty good documentation - 16.4. Associations

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-associations

The `QueryOver` syntax would look like this

```
IQueryOver<Table1, Table2> myQuery = 
  session.QueryOver<Table1>()
   .Left.JoinQueryOver<Table2>(t => t.Table2s)
     .Where(
       Restrictions.Or(
         Restrictions.On<Table2>((t2) => t2.ID).IsNull, 
         Restrictions.On<Table2>((t2) => t2.Field).IsLike("value")
         )
       );
var list = myQuery.List<Table1>();
```

then the `list` will return the collection of all combinations meeting the criteria. *(Later order by or distinct or other porjections could be added...)*

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but somewhat limiting.  What if `Table1` not only has a collection of `Table2`s, but `Table3`s which you also want to filter.  The method provided only accommodates two entities.  Is there a more generic method?  Is there another approach altogether?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes! ;) The NHibernate Criteria API is very powerful. You can use projections (select some properties, select distinct... sum, avg) you can join anyhow... you can filter in the WHERE clause...Anything. Please, take a look documentation  (http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria) or Ayende's blog

Comment: Do you have a working example?  I don't find the documentation particularly helpful for my example.  I tried to implement your suggestion above, neglectiong "Table3" for now, and got back no results.  If you have a working example that uses the powerful Criteria API with multiple mapped collections, that would be a great help!

Comment: There is a starting point, where to continue: when finished the query *as in my answer above*, you can continue adding new criteria: `myQuery.RootCriteria.CreateCriteria(...`